# How to clear the icon cache of Chromium browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I updated my website's icon that shows at a tab of a browser. I cleared the data of the chromium browser (Ubuntu's version of Chrome):

'clear browsing data'->select 'from the beginning of time' and check everything->click 'clear browsing data'

However, I am still getting my old icon.

Any idea of how to clear that cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the favicon URL in another tab and do a Shift+Reload to fix this issue.

For example if Favicon URL is http://www.example.com/favicon.ico, open it in a new tab and do Shift+Reload.

Comment: Since I ended up here from a google search, I'll add that this technique works in other operating systems too (in particular, Mac OS)

Comment: What do you mean by "Reload"?

Comment: "Reload" can be a dedicated key, or F5, or Ctrl+R.  So e.g. Shift+F5 or Shift+Ctrl+R.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still see it. Even after opening dev console, then right clicking on refresh -> Hard Refresh and Empty Cache.. I still see it

Comment: THis doesn't work anymore 2023

Answer (score 1):

You can send a different version of the same ico with a random get var
(if your file is a .php)

```
<link href="ico.png?v=<?php echo rand(9999999,9999999999);?>" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. This one worked.